# Merge SQL With Condition

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a Scenario where i need to User Merge SQL statement to Synchronize two Tables. Let's suppose i have two tables Table A and Table B. Schema is same with the exception of one Extra Column in Table A. That Extra column is a flag that tells me which records are ready to be inserted/updated in Table B. Lets say that flag column is IsReady. It will be either true or False.

Can i use Isready=True in Merge Statement or I need a Temp table to move all records from Table A to Temp Table where IsReady=True and then use Merge SQL on TempTable and Table B???

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use that column in the merge condition.

```
merge tableB targetTable
using tableA sourceTable
on sourceTable.IsReady = 1 and [any other condition]
when not matched then
insert ...
when matched and [...] then
update ...
```

Comment: That does not work if i do it like                             merge tableB targetTable
using tableA sourceTable
on sourceTable.IsReady = 1 and b.key=a.key   It Merge both tables but regardless of a.Isready=True

Comment: Post your merge statement in the OP - you typed something wrong. There is no reason whatsoever it should not work.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you,

```
merge into tableB 
using tableA  
on tableB.IsReady=true
when not matched then
insert (tableB.field1,tableB.field2..)
values (tableA.field1,tableA.field2..);
commit;
```